# crispin.Fop Apache Fop C# port

Tags: c#, pdf, apache-fop

I was using the package for a while now and it was working fine. 
After the update to the latest Package the code broke.

After initializing the factory with some default constructor
I get an error:

```
'org.apache.fop.render.ImageHandlerRegistry' threw an exception.
```

Anyone got an idea how the configuratin should look like so it will work again?

```
    public string GeneratePdf(string foFile, string pdfFile)
    {
        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(pdfFile)));
        string ret = "";
        try
        {
            // Factory before update
            FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
            // After the update the Factory needs some sort of configuration
            // I tryed with all the constructors but can't get the sample to work.
            FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(null);
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop("application/pdf", os);
            FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fop.getUserAgent();
            javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory factory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
            javax.xml.transform.Source src = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(new java.io.File(foFile));
            javax.xml.transform.Result res = new javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
            transformer.transform(src, res);

            ret = pdfFile;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            os.close();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual source of the problem was probably not the upgrade of the crispin, but of the IKVM 8 dependency package, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30887042/993388 seems to describe a similar problem.

After I have downgraded IKVM back from 8.x to 7.x, the problem was gone. Also make sure to remove or adjust any binding redirects to IKVM 8.x from `App.Config`, otherwise the runtime could still try to grab the newer assemblies.

This is only a workaround, but it is the best I could find at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but, this works for me:

```
var jFopFactory = org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance(new java.net.URI("."));
```

I have not tried with any images or other resources though.